# How to make one checkbox control other checkboxes and each one has it's own set to control

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have 3 checkboxes (can have more) like below

[image]

What if I want to have checkboxes behave like the following

- Checking Complete will only check Complete
- Checking Partially Complete will also check Complete
- Checking Unusable will also check Partially Complete and Complete

and

- Unchecking Complete will also uncheck Partially Complete and Unusable
- Unchecking Partially Complete will also uncheck Unusable
- Unchecking Unusable will only uncheck Unusable

Comment: Doing this is a waste of time. You can handle this all on the back end after submission. Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a  code writing service

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to track these items as a single `status` object...

```
<label> Complete </label>
<input type="checkbox"
         [(ngModel)]="status.complete"
         (change)="checkValue('complete')"/>  


<label> Partial </label>
<input type="checkbox"
         [(ngModel)]="status.partial"
         (change)="checkValue('partial')"/>  


<label> Unusable </label>
<input type="checkbox"
         [(ngModel)]="status.unusable"
         (change)="checkValue('unusable')"/>
```

.. in .ts

```
status: any;

ngOnInit() {
this.status={complete:false, partial:false, unusable:false} ;

checkValue(which:string){
  if (this.status[which]) {
     // item is checked
     switch (which) {
       case 'complete':
       this.status.partial = false;
       this.status.unusable = false;
       break;

       case 'partial':
       this.status.complete = true;
       this.status.unusable = false;
       break;

       case 'unusable':
       this.status.complete = this.status.partial = true;
       break;
      }
  } else {
    // item is unchecked
    switch (which) {
       case 'complete':
       this.status.partial = false;
       this.status.unusable = false;
       break;

       case 'partial':
       this.status.unusable = false;
       break;

      }
  } 
}

}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I also can have more than 3 boxes eventually. I was looking for a more dynamic solution